# Ubuntu Won't Boot after Installation

Tags: boot

Title says it all. I am writing this from my phone because I am incapacitated. I was tired of using Windows 7 so I thought I'd give Linux a try. I create a live USB with the ISO and a handy program that creates USBs you can boot from. I launch up a VM and boot Ubuntu. Everything works fine. I boot from USB on my main rig and hit "Try Ubuntu". Everything works fine. I restart my comp, back in Windows. OK, I'm ready to make the plunge. Go to install ubuntu, wipe my entire 500gb hdd. Installation is fine, I'm asked to reset. I reset, and it boots from the USB, ok... I restart and go to my boot menu. Only my USB and CD drive show up. I've tried all the other instillation options, reinstall, install ubuntu alongside ubuntu, wipe disk and install ubuntu, nothing works. I tried everything multiple times and nothing has worked, I am on a endless loop. What do I do? I tried looking up solutions on the internet but nothing has helped. Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Here is my boot-repair info:
http://paste2.org/LPtPKga9

Specs:

WD Blue 500GB Sata Desktop Hard Drive

AMD Phenom II X6 Processor

8Gb Kingston Ram

AMD R7 240 Radeon Graphics Card

MSi 760GM - P23 (FX)

250 W Power Supply

[installing Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXHcz.jpg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47494/discussion-on-question-by-maciej-kedzierski-ubuntu-wont-boot-after-installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extended discussion, we wound up doing this:

1. downloaded the Ubuntu Live DVD .iso
2. ran sha1sum and sha256sum against the .iso file and compared the results to the sha1sums and sha256sums files
3. reset the BIOS to default settings
4. burned the .iso to DVD
5. installed Ubuntu from the DVD
6. reset the boot order in the BIOS
7. boot Ubuntu from HDD fine!